# C++ Base Class using Derived Class Template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the following kind of classes from the dlib project.

```
template<typename EXP>
class matrix_exp
{
public:
    //typedef matrix<type, NR, NC, mem_manager_type, layout_type> matrix_type;
    matrix_exp()
    {
        cout << "matrix_exp()" << endl;
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "matrix_exp" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, long num_rows, long num_cols, typename mem_manager, typename layout>
class matrix: public matrix_exp<matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols, mem_manager, layout> >
{
public:

    void foo()
    {
        cout << "matrix" << endl;
    }
};
```

How is the based class uses derived class as it's template? They have also used typedef matrix matrix_type; inside the matrix_exp. Can someone clarify how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/).

There is a [StackOverflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crtp) just for CRTP.

The [history of CRTP is on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: There's no need to answer such an obvious duplicate; just flag it.

Comment: Thnaks, the term is new to me. It is great to know the term though.